# emu8086 DUP Directive with dwords?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I'm having problems understanding the DUP directive.
When I initialize an array with the following code:

```
t1 dd 2 dup(25ABh), 12h
```

I can see the following data stored in the data segment:

```
14 00 00 00 12 00 00 00
```

Why is it not `AB 25 00 00 AB 25 00 12 00 00 00`?

If I delete the dup directive and write `t1 dd 25ABh, 12h` instead, I get the expected
`AB 25 00 00 12 00 00 00`

In emu8086's GUI:
[image: Screenshot of the result I get]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dup` is not an instruction, it's an assembler directive, and its behavior may vary between assemblers.  So tell us what assembler you're using.

Comment: 8086, running in emu8086

Comment: I think you're using it properly; emu8086 might be broken.  I don't have JWASM installed locally (an open-source assembler that uses MASM-style directives), but it's on https://tio.run/##Vc3NCsIwDAfwe54itynMYSs@gKJXX0BEYlNQadfRVN2evm46/DgE8iP/JCRi/cl1s@uDxOdcMSWCpJAZNfKtmejlan2ellhQAVCZwBaOkigmbGIwgIg@3NFSW6L6iC@jnCWM0muf1OE77sN6PlA6MeQcDH0b4muzr7@zeqF@o@N3W3MD290G3875CQ.  (But I had to write a `_start` that makes a Linux write system call, so the 00 bytes are unprinting.  Still, I do see `«%«%` so there's something repeated twice, before a printable `'a'` that I used instead of 12h)

Comment: (And BTW, this wouldn't be the first bug someone's run into in emu8086, and posted about on Stack Overflow.  It's not a great assembler, and AFAIK isn't being developed / maintained anymore.)

Comment: It's an EMU8086 bug with `DD` directive (it should work with `DW`). You will have to avoid using DUP when the data size is a double word (DD). If you use a real MASM or compatible assembler it would work as you expect.